What effect does a sideslip have on the lift of a plane?
What effect does a sideslip have on the lift of a plane?

When doing some research prior to this question I found this answer, but it didn't really describe what happens to the wing itself.
Is there some sort of spanwise flow that occurs?

If given thee choices:  1.) Increase lift, 2.) Decrease lift, 3.)  No change - Which one would you instinctively choose?

@MichaelHall I would definitely say 2. But I don’t know why this is the case.

I would agree.  I will let the math experts confirm our intuitions with formulas if that is what you are looking for.  The short answer is along the lines of effectively reducing the span.

@MichaelHall I think I should also definitely rephrase this question, as my main question is about what happens to the wingtips + tip vortices.

Then you should also clarify what you mean by "what happens"...  Because it's equally intuitive that they won't stream straight back perpendicular to the wing, right?

@MichaelHall Yeah good point. I will make another smaller edit to clarify some more.

@Wyatt -- re " as my main question is about what happens to the wingtips + tip vortices."-- among other things, there is a roll torque generated by the displaced tip vortices, even on an unswept wing with zero dihedral with (hypothetically) zero fuselage-wing interference.  Can't remember which direction it is off the top of my head.

@quietflyer Are you talking about the downwash created from the tip vortices? I thought that the tip vortices created downwash, but then I asked Mr.Kämpf and turns out that isn’t accurate. That’s actually what sparked this question.

During a sideslip, the airflow is not parallel to the wing section, with the working aerofoil being altered, and the flow is besides perturbed by the fuselage. The effective wing area decreases, resulting in lower lift and higher drag.
